# Open a web browser in C# XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, browser

Under certain conditions, I would like to open a web browser of some sort directly from a C# XNA game. The browser would be pointing to a site I would specify. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [`Process.Start(url)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx).

Note that it won't work on the XBox. (Obviously)

Answer (score 0):

Probably he means inside his apps and if that is the case, no there is no preconfigured way. You should create an HTML parser (or find one online) and link it to your renderer engine, draw the page, etc..et...etc..
Quite a long job, but not impossible. :P

And yes, I don't know which restriction are posed onto the XboX game, but I doubt it will give your app free unrestricted internet access.

Comment: Actually, I was wondering if it would make sense to use HTML to draw the user interface for my game... (I'm new to XNA). Can I just use IE's HTML renderer and have it be overlaid on my game screen?

Comment: @Rosarch: No, you can't.  IE cannot render transparently.